# Use of genitive

Tags: possessives

I was reading an English document when I noticed something:

> #### RFC 4033 [Section 8.1.]
>
> It is important to note the distinction between a RRset's TTL value and the signature validity period specified by the RRSIG RR covering that RRset.

I understand the use of the genitive in *RRset's TTL*, because they are talking about the TTL of the RRset. But why didn't they use it with *the signature validity period*? They are talking about the validity period of the signature, right?!

Comment: English does not have a genitive case. It has possessive pronouns, which function _like_ pronouns inflected in the genitive case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily.

> the signature's validity period

would be understood as *validy period* being a property of *signature*.

Whereas

> the signature validity period

is simply a proper name composed of three words. A technical term, meaning the time during which the signature is valid.

Compare:

- Bob's haircut
  describing how a certain person wears his hair vs.
- Bob haircut
  as the name of a hairstyle where all hair is cut at the same length somewhere between the chin and the shoulder of the wearer.

Answer (score 1):

In English, nouns can be used as adjectives: "airplane glue", that is, the glue used when making model airplanes.  Nouns are said to be used *attributively* when they're used as adjectives.

These nouns-as-adjectives can be chained or stacked up:

**model airplane glue**

In technical writing such concatenation is very typical, because it is perceived to be a terse and efficient style.

The following sentence

> It is important to note the distinction between a RRset's TTL value
>   and the signature validity period specified by the RRSIG RR covering
>   that RRset.

could be made more verbose:

**It is important to note the distinction between the RRset's time-to-live ("TTL") and the period during which the signature remains valid (the "Signature Validity Period") as specified by the RRSIG RR that covers the RRset.**

With respect to your question, why didn't the author use a possessive?

The noun in question is "signature". Yes, the author could have written:

**... the signature's validity period**